# Using Microsoft Access with Java without the JdbcOdbc default bridge

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

we have to use in our project some legacy Microsoft Access 97/2000 databases with Java.
The problem is: we face many problems with the default JdbcOdbc driver which is available on the JDK (memory leaks are the most common issue).

So here is my question: is there any other JDBC Driver we could use (open source whould be great) to achieve this task?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the alternative: http://www.csv-jdbc.com/stels_mdb_jdbc.htm

Comment: Thanks for that link! But - isn't that driver limited to MS Excel?

Comment: Actually this is ALMOST what I need. This driver does not work with Access 97 :(

Comment: Ouch... almost :( You may try contacting them and see if such a thing is feasible.

Answer (score 1):

[HXTT](http://www.hxtt.com/access.html) and [StelsMDB](http://www.csv-jdbc.com/stels_mdb_jdbc.htm) seems to be the most "famous" providers of type 4 JDBC driver for MS Access. The first one supports version from 95, 97, 2000, XP, 2002, to 2003 (and thus meets your requirements). The other one supports MS Access 2000, 2002, 2003, XP.

[Easysoft](http://www.easysoft.com/applications/microsoft-access/jdbc-odbc.html) is another alternative but is a JDBC type 3 driver (i.e. a bridge type).

All are commercial products.

Comment: +1 for reminding of HXTT. I knew there was one, but didn't recall anymore.

Comment: i'm experiencing a lot of problems using HXTT , a lot of queries with join resturn unconsistent results , has anyone experiencing such thing ?