# JDBC Driver for MsAccess which will work on Unix

Tags: java, open-source, jdbc, ms-jet-ace

I need a JDBC driver for MsAccess to be used in a Unix environment

I would strongly prefer it to be an open-source

Also it should support SQL statements

(Jackcess came close to being my choice- but it doesn't support SQL queries)
http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/faq.html#query

Comment: "doesn't support SQL queries"? What *does* does this JDBC driver do?

Comment: I think its an API rather than a JDBC driver

Comment: Apparently not :) We are using third party applications which uses MsAccess

Comment: ouch! Why would you do this?  Put the data on Unix or move the app to Windows!

Comment: Its a third party which generates MDB files- i have zero control on that. My challenge is to move the data generated into oracle database in an unix based enterprise application

Comment: "Doesn't support queries" means it doesn't support the Query objects in Access databases, not that it doesn't support SQL queries. I'm not sure whether the JDBC-ODBC bridge in Sun's Windows JRE supports those Query objects either -- I suspect it doesn't.

Comment: To @Bozho: Access isn't actually involved in this question, only the default database engine that ships with Access, Jet/ACE. Neither Access nor the Jet/ACE database engine is obsolete, as MS is pouring a whole lot of new development resources into it. You should seriously give the Access 2010 beta a test drive, particularly if you have any chance to use it with Sharepoint.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "Neither Access nor the Jet/ACE database engine is obsolete" -- using Jet 4.0 and earlier with Access Forms apps has been declared as obsolete by MS. Using Jet or ACE as an application data store has been declared as obsolete by MS (other than Access Forms apps and SHarePoint, obviously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use a Type 4 JDBC driver (i.e. full Java), more precisely the driver from [HXTT](http://www.hxtt.com/access.html) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764046/using-microsoft-access-with-java-without-the-jdbcodbc-default-bridge/1764510#1764510) for some alternatives). Sadly, it's not an open source driver and it's not free. But if you are using Oracle, I think you can spend around 300 bucks for a driver.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use a JDBC-ODBC bridge for it.  If you must do SQL, I've found that to be the best way.

Comment: Can you do that on Unix?