# Connect MS Access in Java on Debian Linux machine

Tags: java, linux, ms-access, jdbc, debian

Currently I've developed a small desktop application as an enhancement to my project, which reads '.mdb' file and connects as an MS-Access database using 'JDBC-ODBC Driver'.

This is works fine in Windows environment, but I am unable to run the same on Debian-Linux machine.

The code is below:

```
try 
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    oAccessConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+mdbFileName);
} 
catch (Exception oException) 
{
    logger.info("Exception",oException);
}
```

How can I diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDBC-ODBC bridge won't work in Linux machine, so you have to use other JDBC driver, which will have access to MS-ACCESS directly (not thru ODBC bridge) - try to look in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929592/jdbc-driver-for-msaccess-which-will-work-on-unix)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can find MS Access for Linux, I don't believe this will work.  MS Access needs to run on a supported operating system.

You can run MS Access on a seperate Windows box and access it remotely, or you can install Windows in a virtual machine on the same box e.g. https://www.virtualbox.org/

Or you can use a database which can be used on other OSes. (This is almost any database accept MS Access and MS Sql Server)

Comment: can u suggest any approach for the same ?

Comment: @HarsH, Added some suggestions.  MS insist access run on their Windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to manipulate the file data and don't need to run complex queries, then you could use [jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) to work with the access file (it works on any platform with no extra libraries).  the only downside is that it doesn't support jdbc or have a way of executing sql queries.