# How to Java Persistence Api with MS Access?

Tags: java, jpa

I could not find any jdbc driver for ms access.So how can I connect MS Access with JPA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the only free drivers available are JDBC-ODBC bridges (type 1).

The [JDBC-ODBC Bridge Driver](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) distributed by Sun is `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` and this is what [they write](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/) about it:

> Note that the bridge driver included in the Java Platform Standard Edition (Java SE) 6 is appropriate only for experimental use or when no other driver is available.

And if this is not enough, here is what Ted Neward writes in Item 49 of [Effective Enterprise Java](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=EffectiveJava_Chapter):

> (...) the JDBC-ODBC driver is an unsupported, bug-ridden 1.0 driver that is incredibly slow and is rumored to leak memory in some ODBC driver configurations (...)

Things may be a bit better with the Microsoft one (which is `com.ms.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`) but I wouldn't expect a miracle.

So, if this is for a corporate application, maybe consider spending a few dollars for a commercial type 4 JDBC Driver. See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764046/using-microsoft-access-with-java-without-the-jdbcodbc-default-bridge/1764510#1764510) for some options.

Comment: Also note - in the case of Access and Excel, there is no 64-bit ODBC driver

Comment: @Ibrahim You're welcome. BTW: The common way of recognizing a good answer is upvoting it ;-)

Comment: I never heard about `com.ms.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` and didn't find any info about it via google. Do you have any refs? Does it work with MS Access anyways?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you need a MS driver at all.  Just use a sun ODBC driver. 
Look at the article [here.](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2691&lngWId=2)

Answer (score 0):

I've never needed it, but I've heard good things about this one: http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use UcanAccess: http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html
It is a good replacement for the ODBC driver since Java 8